# How does onDelete() function handler work in a swiftUI List?

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I understand that the following code works:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    func removeRows(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        numbers.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    }
    
    @State private var numbers = [Int]()
    @State private var currentNumber = 1

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(numbers, id: \.self) {
                    Text("\($0)")
                }
                .onDelete(perform: removeRows)
            }

            Button("Add Number") {
                self.numbers.append(self.currentNumber)
                self.currentNumber += 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I don't understand is how the `removeRows(at offsets: IndexSet)` custom function handler for `.onDelete()` works. Specifically, why is there an argument label `at` before `offsets:`. Could you use `on` instead of `at` for example? Is the argument labels just for us to better understand the code?

Then there's `IndexSet` which I think I understand as a type that holds an Int for indexing purposes or ranges of Ints for use in deleting a row in the list, so that swiftui knows which row to delete?

I think I understand `numbers.remove(atOffsets: offsets)` is used to actually do the removing of the list row at `offsets` (in terms of the actual row index being deleted) - but i'm not sure how `offsets` is actually known by swift? What actually is `offsets` and how is it's value set?

I'm trying to learn by following [this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/deleting-items-using-ondelete). I still have a very basic knowledge of swiftui, so please explain like I am super noob at this.

Comment: See [Function Argument Labels and Parameter Names](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html#ID166)

Comment: Thank you @pawello2222, so I realise that answers my question about the argument labels. I assume the swift.org documentation means that we could have used any word as argument label instead of `at` ? (I find the explanation on swift.org not explicit enough for me to understand fully). I still am at a loss for my other questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at the `onDelete` signature:

```
@inlinable public func onDelete(perform action: ((IndexSet) -> Void)?) -> some DynamicViewContent
```

you can see that it expects a parameter of type `((IndexSet) -> Void)?`.

Which means it needs a function accepting `IndexSet` parameter and returning `Void`.

Your `removeRows` function has exactly the same type as needed:

```
func removeRows(at offsets: IndexSet) { ...
```

*The above signature is an equivalent of:

```
func removeRows(at offsets: IndexSet) -> Void { ...
```

---

The label `at` is used for clarity. It could be called `someCustomLabel` as well:

```
func removeRows(someCustomLabel offsets: IndexSet) { ...
```

but then you'd need to call it this way:

```
removeRows(someCustomLabel: indexSet)
```

You can also skip the label altogether:

```
func removeRows(offsets: IndexSet) { ...
```

and call your function like this:

```
removeRows(offsets: indexSet)
```

Note that:

```
.onDelete(perform: removeRows)
```

is the same as:

```
.onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
    self.removeRows(at: indexSet)
})
```

---

The `IndexSet` specifies which indexes to delete. When you swipe left on a row in your `List` it invokes the `onDelete` function passing the row index in the `IndexSet` parameter.

Note that `numbers.remove(atOffsets: offsets)` expects `IndexSet` parameter for the `atOffsets` label (and you can't change this label) but you're free to name your parameter as you want:

```
func removeRows(at indexSetToDelete: IndexSet) {
    numbers.remove(atOffsets: indexSetToDelete)
}
```

Comment: Thank you @pawello2222, this is quite helpful. Just to be clear, when you refer to `indexSet` do you mean to type `IndexSet`? Also, does this mean that when a user swipes left on the row to invoke `onDelete` function, that Swift automatically sends that row index to the IndexSet parameter (`offsets`). Is that an automatic thing that the `onDelete` function does without any need from me to worry about that? Also just to confirm, `IndexSet` is the value type of the parameter `offsets`, right?

Comment: @SuperNoob `IndexSet` is a *type*. `indexSet` in `.onDelete(perform: { indexSet in ...` is some value. As a convention in Swift you use Uppercase for types. And yes, onDelete is called automatically when you swipe to delete. It gives you some set of rows and you can decide what to do with it. I recommend you read more of Swift documentation about [Functions](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html).